# Predicate for NSFetchRequest Core Data based on content in other entity list

Tags: ios, sql, core-data, social-networking

I have the following Core Data Model:

User has attributes username(string) and user_id(integer).

ContactStatus has first_user_id(integer), second_user_id(integer), and status(string which is either "1REQ","2REQ", or "CONF").

I want to get a list of contacts for a given user with a user_id of u_id, the equivalent SQL would be:

```
SELECT first_user_id,second_user_id FROM ContactStatuses WHERE (first_user_id == u_id OR second_user_id == u_id) AND status == 'CONF'
```

Or is there a better way to organize my data in Core Data? This is the way its organized in my MySQL database.

**Edit:**

I have a MySQL database on my server, and in php/sql, if I wanted to return a list of a user's contacts, I would use the above query. As I download this information (in JSON) to my iOS app, I would like to store these users' information in the managed object context. Then, when I want to display a list of contacts to the users, I would want to query the managed object context with a fetch request similar to the above SQL statement. The problem is that I don't know how to filter users with a predicate that comes from a different entity, the contactstatus entity.

Comment: What do you mean list of contacts? Would it be a list of people for each separate `username`?

Comment: Yeah, im trying to make a fetch request, but I don't know what the predicate would look like.

Comment: So is the data already in a database somewhere? What do you mean fetch? I suggest you edit your question to outline your app project. That will help me hopefully help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreData is an object graph representation of your data, in most cases it is backed up by an SQLite database.
I assume that you need to sync your objects with a server side database and so you must define your own `user_id` property.
However, it might make sense for you to make a relationship between a `User` entity and a `ContactStatus` entity (this depend on your implementation and application needs that you have not listed).

In any case, under your current implementation (assuming your query target entity is `ContactStatus`).

Your predicate should look something like:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(first_user_id = %@ OR second_user_id) AND status = %@",@(u_id),@(u_id),@"CONF"];
```

Comment: So I would get a list of these ContactStatuses, then how would I get a list of users that are either of the first_user_id or second_user_id? Would I have to create another NSFetchedResultsController?

Comment: Oh! Instead of making a contactStatus be composed of integers of user_ids, it should just have a relationship for both the first_user_id and second_user_id right?

Comment: Exactly. To get a `User` from a `ContactsStatus` you will need a relationship between them.